# Is there a way to bring back swipe to unlock in iOS10

Tags: ios

I there a way to restore the swipe to unlock in iOS 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with the stock, non-jailbroken device.  Apple has decided to move away from that method of opening the iDevice.  I don't see them changing their mind and putting it back so it's probably best to learn how to use it going forward.

Comment: RIP. Apple UX department

Comment: I don't know, I actually like how it works in iOS 10.  Change is always hard and for some people it's something they never overcome.  If this answers your question, please be sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: Yes and no. Assimilating to change is ideal in new technology like moving from angularjs 1 to angular js 2. But his is a bad joke. It's slower unlock the phone now. Especially when you need a passcode.

Comment: I thought it would be slower for me, too, but then I learned I could change the home button action.  Does the iPhone have Touch ID?  If so, look at [this article](https://www.igeeksblog.com/disable-press-home-to-unlock-in-ios-10/) on how make unlocking faster.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://www.igeeksblog.com/slide-to-unlock-in-ios-10/), you apparently could in iOS 10 beta 1 by making a backup, editing a file and then using iTunes to restore the backup to your phone. This functionality may, however, was removed in a future iOS update.

This implies that either you need to jailbreak your device to do something like that; otherwise there's no way to do so on stock iOS.

Answer (score -2):

Downgrade to iOS 9.3.5 if you want.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way.